# Fire off function after multiple times

Tags: swift

How can i fire off an function when a user opens up the app more than twice a day?
For example, it is monday. The user opens the app 2 times on that day, than a function is triggered. But the next day the process must start again.

I have this code for saving the number that an app launced:

```
var numLaunches = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("numLaunches") + 1
```

But how can i do this in combination of the current day?

Comment: Also store the current day - when you read it, if it's different than today, you know it's a brand new day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this class to store info about the day and the number of times you app has been launched for the specified day.

```
@objc class MyStats : NSObject, NSCoding {
    private var date: NSDate
    private(set) var launchCounter: Int

    override init() {
        date = NSDate()
        launchCounter = 1
    }

    @objc func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(NSDate(), forKey: "date")
        aCoder.encodeInteger(launchCounter, forKey: "launchCounter")
    }

    @objc required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.date = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("date") as! NSDate
        self.launchCounter = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("launchCounter")
    }

    func increaseLaunchCounter() {
        launchCounter++
    }

    var isAboutToday: Bool {
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let unitFlags = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay
        let comp1 = calendar.components(unitFlags, fromDate: NSDate())
        let comp2 = calendar.components(unitFlags, fromDate: self.date)
        return comp1.day == comp2.day && comp1.month == comp2.month && comp1.year == comp2.year
    }

    func save() {
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: "stats")
    }

    class func loadStats() -> MyStats? {
        if let
            data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("stats") as? NSData,
            stats = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as? MyStats {
            return stats
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

To use it just add this function to your `AppDelegate`.

```
private func checkStats() {
    if let stats = MyStats.loadStats() where stats.isAboutToday {
        stats.increaseLaunchCounter()
        stats.save()
        print("The app has been launched \(stats.launchCounter) today")
        // call your function...
    } else {
        MyStats().save()
    }
}
```

And finally call it inside `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    checkStats()
    return true
}
```